# Multi dependent claims (Uses and Advantages)

Tags: patentability, patent-infringement, patent-applications, patent-services, google-patents

What is the significance of multi dependent claims in infringement analysis?
What are the advantages in claiming multi dependent claims over normal claims?

Comment: in the Us or somewhere else?

Comment: Anywhere (e.g. US, EPO, CN, or JP) where these are allowed

Answer (score 1):

They provide a way to cover many combinations and permutations of elements in a relatively few numbered claims. The semantics are no different than exploding the claims to a huge number of non-multiply dependent claims. The U.S. thinks they are confusing and strongly discourages them via is fee system. The rest of the world sees them as using fewer words to achieve the same meaning and therefore simpler.